# Pick's Theorem and Primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-geometry, primality-test

For $n$ prime, each of the remaining triangles contains exactly the same number of grid points.
This was proved [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/PickApps.shtml).

[image: picks_theorem]

However, is the converse true i.e., triangles containing exactly the same number of grid points implies a prime? I tried (geometrically) finding a non-prime which had the same number of internal grid points, but the lattice became too noisy to accurately manage.

Thanks.

Comment: For future readers: when $n$ is prime each such triangle contains $(n-1)/2$ grid points (other than its vertices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n > 1$ be a positive integer and for each $0 \le i < n$, let $\Delta_n(i)$ be the triangle with coordinates at $(0,0)$, $(i,n-i)$ and $(i+1, n-(i+1))$.

Euclidean geometry tells us that these triangles have the same area since they have the same base and height if you take the base as the $((i,n-i), (i+1,n-(i+1)))$ edge and the height as the orthogonal segment to $((0,n), (n,0))$ that drops from the origin, namely the segment $((0,0), (n/2,n/2))$. So by Pick's theorem, denoting by $B_n(i)$ and $I_n(i)$ the number of grid points on the boundary and interior of $\Delta_n(i)$ respectively, we see that the quantity $2B_n(i) + I_n(i)$ must be constant when $i$ varies from $0$ to $n-1$ because $2B_n(i) + I_n(i) = 2 \, \mathrm{Area}(\Delta_n(i)) + 2$.

You'll notice two exceptions to the rule that the number of interior points remains the same, namely for the triangles $\Delta_n(0)$ and $\Delta_n(n-1)$; the problem with those two is that they share $n+1$ points with the $x$-axis (resp. $y$-axis) and one point at $(1,n-1)$ (resp. $(n-1,1)$), and no interior point. It doesn't help us figure out if $n$ is prime per se, but it gives us the value of
$$
2B_n(i) + I_n(i) = 2(n+2) = 2n+4. 
$$
Here is the case where $n=7$:

[image: The figure with n=7]

And here is the case where $n=6$:

[image: The figure with n=6]

I labelled the intersection points with the integer grid for visibility. So basically the only way that $\Delta_n(i)$ will have the same number of interior points when $i=1,\cdots,n-2$ is if it also has the same number of boundary points by Pick's theorem, since those triangles all have the same area and all have integer coordinate vertices.

But how is it possible that a line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(i,n-i)$ intersects points on the integer grid? This happens if there exists a rational number $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ such that $\lambda i$ and $\lambda(n-i)$ are both integers. Writing $\lambda = a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime, this means in particular that $a<b$ and $b$ divides both $i$ and $n-i$. The existence of such a $b$ is necessary and sufficient to find an intersection point on the integer grid with the segment (we can just take $a=1$) and $b$ exists if and only if $\gcd(i,n-i) > 1$. But $\gcd(i,n-i) = \gcd(i,n)$, so basically each integer $i$ between $1$ and $n-1$ satisfying $g_n(i) \overset{def}= \gcd(i,n) > 1$ will have $g_n(i) - 1$ points of intersection with the integer grid (excluding $(i,n-i)$ and $(0,0)$), namely corresponding to the values of $\lambda$ equal to $\frac 1{g_n(i)}, \frac 2{g_n(i)}, \cdots, \frac{g_n(i)-1}{g_n(i)}$.

We now show that the number of interior points of $\Delta_n(i)$ for $i=1,\cdots,n-2$ are going to be the same if and only if $n$ is prime or $n=4$, because in the first case, $g_n(i) = 1$ for $i=1,\cdots,n-1$, and in the second case, $g_4(1)=1, g_4(2)=2$ and $g_4(3) = 1$, so $g_4(1)+g_4(2) = g_4(2) + g_4(3)$.

The number $n=4$ is the only number small enough not to be prime that works, because whenever $n > 4$ and $n$ has a prime divisor say $p > 2$, we have $g_n(1) = 1$ and $g_n(2) = 1$ or $2$, but $g_n(p) = p$ and $g_n(p+1) = 1$. If $n$ is a power of $2$ greater than $4$, we have $g_n(1) = 1$ and $g_n(2) = 2$ but $g_n(n/2) = n/2$ and $g_n(n/2+1) = 1$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: There seems to be a leap of logic in the last sentence. One needs to show that the only case in which $g_n(i)+g_n(i+1)$ is constant for $i=1,\dots,n-2$ is when $g_n(i)=1$ for all $i=1,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: @GregMartin : True, there is a small leap, but most of the work is done already. I'll add a quick fix

Comment: @GregMartin : You were right to be careful, I had missed the case $n=4$!

Comment: Thanks! Basically, to sum this up for a non-technical maths person (i.e., myself), only primes and $4$ (I missed that too) have the same number of interior points. Is that correct?

Comment: @vengy: Yes. Basically the intuition was right, that when $n$ is prime all the points contributing to the area coming from Pick's theorem will come from the interior and the vertices of the triangle, not the boundary. But in general, the case $n=4$ is the only case where some points are in the boundary and yet they all have the same number of boundary points; it's sort of a "small $n$ exception" to the rule.

Comment: Given this result, could an efficient PDS primality test be devised? ;) Thanks.

Comment: @vengy: Hahaha I don't think so. I mean checking the area of each of those triangles is much more computationally expensive than factoring an integer.

Comment: @vengy: Sure, but if you're talking about a primality test, you need an algorithm, and simulating that "camera" that detects if the point is not "visible" from the origin will be more computationally expensive than just factoring the integer. And I'm not talking about the overhead here, I'm literally saying that the algorithm will be slower in terms of O-notation. For instance, if you take the product of two very large prime numbers, looking at each individual point on the hypothenuse of your triangle until you can find the smallest of the two primes takes $O(\sqrt n)$ steps. This is not fast.