# Is it possible to prove Infinite Primes using Picks Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-geometry

***Lemma:*** Triangles containing exactly the same number of grid points (excluding boundary), then $n$ is prime. (see [Pick's Theorem and Primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968472/picks-theorem-and-primes))

***Claim:*** There exists infinite such triangles, so infinite primes.

Is that claim provable?

[image: 2Dlattice]

**Note:** I only know basic high-school level maths. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the statement of the lemma.  What is $\Delta_n$?

Comment: I think it might help to attach some reference, such as [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/PickApps.shtml) to explain the context.  I don't see any sensible way to deduce that there are infinitely many primes from this construction, but who knows?  It's still a nice result.

Comment: I edited the question to remove that delta symbol and added a reference to the lemma. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is completely unclear. But presumably it refers to your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968472/picks-theorem-and-primes). The answer there proved that each of the $n-2$ triangles contains the same number of lattice points in its interior if and only if $n=4$ or $n$ is prime.

If you had some **independent** way of proving that there were infinitely many $n$ for which the $n-2$ triangles each contain the same number of points in their interiors, then you would be able to deduce that there were infinitely many primes. But until you can find such a way, you will have to be content with the existing one-line proof that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Yep, I was hoping some magic lattice maths existed to prove it. But, I'm content with the one-liner proofs for now. Thanks!